# Jquery AJAX Post: 500 (Internal Server Error)? in Symfony 3

Tags: php, html, ajax, symfony-3.3

I am trying post an id to Controller action  but I am getting this error :
(I am using Symfony 3).

jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/plate/web/app_dev.php/province_ajax_call?province_id=2 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my ajax code :

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
{{ form(form_account) }}


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#appbundle_account_Province').change(function(){
        var val = $('#appbundle_account_Province').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ url('province_ajax_call') }}?province_id=" + val,
            success: function(data){
                $('#appbundle_account_City').html('');
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    $('#appbundle_account_City').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
               })
               console.log('succes');
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Here is My controller code :

```
public function provinceAjaxCallAction(Request $request)
{

    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    $id = $request->query->get('province_id');
    var_dump($id);

    $cities = $this
              ->getDoctrine()
              ->getManager()
              ->getRepository('AppBundle:City')
              ->findByProvinceId($id);

    $result = array();
    foreach($cities as $city){
        $result[$city->getId()] = $city->getName();
    }
    return new JsonResponse($result);
}

public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $account = new Account();

    $form = $this->createForm(AccountType::class, $account);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($account);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('test_registration_homepage');
    }

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array('form_account' => $form->createView()));


}
}
```

Comment: It can be anything, starting from a typo in config files. 

You can see logs - they will tell you exactly what went wrong with the request.

Comment: I check logs but I didn't understand anything

Comment: @Sabra, which logs did you check? Maybe you checked the wrong logs? If you were checking your PHP logs, and did not understand it, post the error message here so that we can let you know what it means. You will not get very far with any project you are working on if you do not learn how to read the error log messages.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by adding

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```

in the controller.